# The 2 useEffect() hooks that i used in my drummachine are clustering

Tags: reactjs

Wrote my drum-machine code and it perfectly works using mouse as i toggle from drumpad A-B, but on  using useEffect() hooks to make it react to keypress separately, they clutter each other. When i switch from drum kick to piano for example and i press the keypad, the sound from drum kick buttons plays together with piano buttons and vice-versa... please how do i solve this? here is the code

````
    
   const arrBank1 = useSelector((state)=>state.playNow.map(loop=>loop));
   const arrPiano = useSelector((state)=>state.playPiano.map(loop=>loop));
   const [switchOn, switchOff] = useState(false);
   const [bank, setBank] = useState(false);

   //const [play, setPlay] = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(bank===false ){
            document.addEventListener("keydown", (event)=>{
            
                arrBank1.map(keys2=>{
                    for(let i = 0; i<keys2["id"].length; i++){
                        if((event.key.toUpperCase()=== keys2["value"][i])){     
                            handlePlay(event.key.toUpperCase(),keys2["id"]);   
                        }
                    }
                })
            })   
        }
   })   

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(bank===true){
            document.addEventListener("keydown", (event)=>{
                
                arrPiano.map(keys=>{
                    for(let i = 0; i<keys["id"].length; i++){
                        if((event.key.toUpperCase() === keys["value"][i])){                 
                            handlePlay(keys["id"],keys["id"]);
                        }
                    }
                }) 
                
            }) 
        }
            
    })

    //This function changes or handles the bank switch toggle from drum kicks to piano
    const handleBankSwitch = () =>{
        setBank(!bank);
            if(bank===false){
                document.getElementById("bank1But").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("bank2But").style.display="grid";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("bank1But").style.display="grid";
                document.getElementById("bank2But").style.display="none";
            }
    }
   //This function handles the playing of the audios
    const handlePlay = (playId,showId) =>{
        if(switchOn === true){
            //document.getElementById(playId).duration=1;
            document.getElementById(playId).play();
            document.getElementById("display").innerText= showId;
        }       
    }
   //This function handles the display of the switch toggle
    const handleSwitch=()=>{
        switchOn===true?document.getElementById("switch").innerText = "OFF":
        document.getElementById("switch").innerText = "ON";
    }

    return(
        
        <Container fluid className='bigContainer'>
            <div className="drum-container">
                <div className='bothButtons' id="bank1But" >
                    {arrBank1.map(i=>{
                        return <div key={i.value}>
                            <Button id='button1' className="button"  onClick={()=>handlePlay(i.value,i.id)} >{i.value}</Button>
                            <audio src={i.url} id={i.value}></audio>
                        </div> 
                    })}
                </div>
                
               <div className='bothButtons' id="bank2But" style={{display:"none"}}>
                    {arrPiano.map(j=>{
                        return <div key={j.url}>
                            <Button id='button2' className="buttons"  onClick={()=>handlePlay(j.id,j.id)} >{j.value}</Button>
                            <audio src={j.url} id={j.id}></audio>
                        </div> 
                    })}
                </div>`enter code here```
````

Comment: Use only one `useEffect` and add the dependencies

Comment: You are using `getElementById` everywhere. This is not how react supposed to be used.

Comment: please, what do i use instead of getElementById?? I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching event listeners to `window`, but never removing them. This means when you switch to the drum kit, the piano event listeners will still be attached, and vice versa. You need to [remove the previously attached event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) before adding new ones.

I also noticed that your effects don't specify dependency arrays. This means they will run, and thus attach event listeners, on every render. You should only change the event listeners when `bank` changes - you can achieve this by [adding a dependency array to your `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

Comment: thanks, let me give this a try again... I appreciate

Comment: YES !!! It finally worked..... Thanks